# What is a recommended way of thransferring am iocage jail from one host to another

Tags: freebsd, rsync, zfs, jail

Source iocage thick jail running on FreeBSD-12.0p12
Destination FreeBSD-12.1p1

Both hosts are using zfs.

What is the recommended method to transfer an existing iocage thick jail from the source to the destination?  Is it as simple as:

```
rsync -aqz -e "ssh -o LogLevel=error"  /zroot/iocage/jails/testjail \
                           destination:/zroot/iocage/jails
```

Presuming that iocage is installed on both hosts, that the zfs mount points are as indicated above, that the source jail is shutdown, and that testjail does not exist on the destination host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iocage comes with a great export/import function.

```
$ man iocage
...
     export        Exports the specified jail.  An archive file is created in
               /iocage/images with an SHA256 checksum.  The jail must be
               stopped before exporting.

               Example:

                     # iocage export examplejail_2
```

Then transfer the file to your new host, import it there, and voilà!